# Mondrian: Filter greater than or less than in a Time Dimension

Tags: date, filter, mdx, mondrian

I am having difficulty filtering a time dimension.

I have a Time Dimension with a date level that is derived from sql function -> DATE( TimeStampBegin )

I want to filter where the date is greater than 2014-03-03:

```
select NON EMPTY [Users].[Trial].Members ON COLUMNS,  
NON EMPTY[Problem Areas].[Fridges] ON ROWS from [Search]
WHERE (Filter([Time].[Date].Members, [Time].[Date].CurrentMember > [2014-03-03]))
```

The result set I get is:

```
Axis #0:
{[Time].[2014-02-28]}
{[Time].[2014-03-04]}
{[Time].[2014-03-10]}
{[Time].[2014-03-13]}
Axis #1:
{[Users].[ILearnTrial2014]}
Axis #2:
{[Problem Areas].[Fridges]}
Row #0: 161
```

As you can see, the Time member returned includes 2014-02-28 which is not greater than 2014-03-03.

If I change to 2014-03-03 I get:

```
Axis #0:
{[Time].[2014-02-28]}
{[Time].[2014-03-10]}
Axis #1:
{[Users].[ILearnTrial2014]}
Axis #2:
{[Problem Areas].[Fridges]}
Row #0: 93
```

As you can see there is no relationship between the greater than date and what Time].[Date] members are returned.

I am also trying [Time].[Hour] and the results show the same inconsistencies.

Can anyone help?

***EDIT***
I'd like to pass on the solution to my problem in the spirit in which these forums are supposed to work.
Thanks to Luc for his pointless and unhelpful comment yesterday.

For anyone interested, filter for the current member name as follows, Filter([Time].[Date].Members, [Time].[Date].CurrentMember.Name > "2014-03-03").

Comment: The way you have written your MDX query clearly shows that you do not understand how MDX works. Please take the time to read a few tutorials first, and your answers shall become quite obvious.